# What is the meaning of "...the most obvious being that..."?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> There are clear ways that doing the subject shaped me; **the most obvious being that** my professional life involves being a secondary school English teacher and a writer.

From [My favourite A-level – and how it shaped my life](https://theguardian.com/commentisfree/2015/aug/13/my-favourite-a-level-how-shaped-life)

What is the meaning of the highlighted phrase in English?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase refers to "ways".
The meaning is "the most obvious *way* that doing the subject shaped me is that...".